# Unload/reload symbols/pdb in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, windbg, symbols

I'm in visual studio 2008, and need to unload a specific module.

In windbg this would be accomplished with

```
.reload -u
```

but I can't find it's counterpart in VS, or any functionality relating to reloading)

Thanks!

Comment: That's not what .reload does.

Comment: Hmm - not sure what you mean; last time I used it I believe it did :) Note that for clarity I simplified it - without a /f force, it only marks them as stale.

@Hans - please provide a correction if you're going to point out something that is wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant - any comment? that is what .reload does in windbg...

Comment: someone suggested this might be it, but it isn't: in the visual studio modules window, right clicking on the dll doesn't give a reload/unload option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apparently does not exist.  Please correct me if that's wrong...